# Python LIFO list/array - shifting data, to replace first input with newest value

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, queue

My goal is to find the highest high in set of price data. However, im currently struggling to append data to a list in a LIFO order (last in first out) in my for loop looping through large set of data. So for example:
I have a list []
append to list item by item in for loop: list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
then I have reached desired list length (in this case 5), I want to shift everything down whilst deleting '1' for example it could go to `[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]` then replace '1' with '6' resulting in `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

```
highs_list = np.array([])
    list_length = 50

for current in range(1, len(df.index)):
        previous = current - 1

        if len(highs_list) < list_length:
            np.append(highs_list, df.loc[current, 'high'])
        else:
            np.roll(highs_list, -1)
            highs_list[49] = df.loc[current, 'high']
```

Comment: Have you tried to look at the Queue module ? 

Here is an exemple that might do what you want.
 https://www.guru99.com/python-queue-example.html

Comment: Your sample code doesn't match the description.  It uses `numpy` which doesn't change size like a list.  And the use of `np.append` doesn't  match the docs.  `roll` is also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insert 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and then want to remove 1 to insert 6 then this seems to be a FIFO movement, since the First IN (1) is the First OUT.

Anyhow, standard Python lists allow for this by using `append()` and `pop(0)`, but the in-memory shift of the elements has time complexity O(n).

A much more efficient tool for this task is `collections.deque`, which also provides a `rotate` method to allow exactly the `[1,2,3,4,5] => [2,3,4,5,1]` transformation.